# Предназначение Page Scope в JSP

Tags: jsp, java

для каких целей может понадобится хранить объекты в *pagecontext*?

Я догадался прочитать в документации, но мне непонятны(семантика) вот эти пункты:

- a number of convenience API's to access various public objects
- a mechanism to manage session usage by the page
- a mechanism to expose page directive attributes to the scripting environment

Буду признателен за объяснения)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Page context` - это просто область видимости переменных для скриптирующего окружения. Причем он работает в обе стороны: видимы в этом контексте атрибуты JSP страницы (неявно добавляются в страничный контекст) так и параметры добавляемые через скриптлеты в коде, например:

```
<%  
String myParm = pageContext.getAttribute("myParm").toString(); //доступ к параметру страницы myParm
pageContext.setAttribute("myParm2", "Hi!"); //задание нового параметра myParm2
%>
```

Для JSP есть 4 области видимости: приложение, сессия, запрос и страница.